# Conflict between WebIntegrationTest and ContextConfiguration in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

When I have a test using both `@WebIntegrationTest` and `@ContextConfiguration`, I find I cannot retrieve the randomly generated port for the Spring Boot application.

My test looks like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class})
@WebIntegrationTest(randomPort = true)
public class SpringBootAppTest{

    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    private int port;

    @Test
    public void testApp(){
      //do test
    }
}
```

And TestConfig looks like:

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    //Override my datasource bean to use a local inmemory HSQL DB
    @Bean(name="datasource")
    public DataSource inMemoryDataSource(){
        JDBCDataSource inMemory = new JDBCDataSource();
        inMemory.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:SERVICE_BROKER;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE");
        return inMemory;
    }

}
```

When I run my test i get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${local.server.port}"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
    at org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.parseNumber(NumberUtils.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor.setAsText(CustomNumberEditor.java:113)
```

If I remove the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation, the app starts on its random port, but it then fails trying to locate the real datasource connection.

How do I make them play nicely together?

Comment: Because you shouldn't be using `@ContextConfiguration` in the first place... You should be using `SpringApplicationConfiguration`. If the only thing you want is change the datasource simply add an `application.properties` to your `src/test/resources` with `spring.datasource.url` with the value you have.

Comment: I'm using Spring Cloud Connectors for Cloud Foundry, simply setting the datasource url will not stop Spring Cloud trying to kick in, which during a test run will fail.

Comment: You are right however, I shouldnt be using ContextConfiguration. I need to add TestConfig.class to the classes list for SpringApplicationConfiguration and all will be well.